# Where does a Laurent Series converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

From the Cauchy integral formula, I get

$f(z)=\int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z}d\zeta$

manipulating, =$\int_{C} f(\zeta)(\frac{1}{\zeta -p -(z-p)})$=$\int_{C} f(\zeta)(\frac{1}{(\zeta -p)(1 -\frac{(z-p)}{\zeta -p}})$=$\int_{C} f(\zeta) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z-p}{\zeta -p})^n$ which is valid for $|\frac{z-p}{\zeta -p}|<1$.

Geometrically, I interpret this as the points closer to $z$ than the boundary of C[image]

Or, I can choose to do a different power series.

$f(z)=\int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z}d\zeta$ = manipulating differently, =$\int_{C} f(\zeta)(\frac{1}{\zeta -p -(z-p)})$=$\int_{C} f(\zeta)(\frac{1}{-(z -p)(1 -\frac{(\zeta-p)}{z -p}})$=$-\int_{C} f(\zeta) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\zeta-p}{z -p})^n$ which is valid for $|\frac{\zeta-p}{z -p}|<1$.

Which I am then interpreting as the outside region of the circle[image]

My question is, as you may have guessed, Where does the Laurent series given by

$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-p)^n +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z-p)^n}$ converge? I do not understand where the annulus of convergence can be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a Laurent series converges between the point where it is constructed around (in your case $p$) and up to the closer singularity to the function that it represent. If the function doesn't have any singularity then the Laurent series is just a Taylor series with radius of convergence infinity

Comment: @Masacroso Here yes but in general the domain of convergence can be any anulus, eg. $\sum_n (1/2)^{|n|} z^n$ converges for $|z| < 1/2, |1/z| < 1/2 = |z| \in (1/2,2)$. The (open) annulus where $\sum_n a_n z^n$ converges is $|z|\in (1/r,R)$ where $R,r$ are the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n,\sum_{n > 0} a_{-n} z^n$. There is a singularity on $|z| = R, |z| =1/r$